# docker - private registry with front webUI (not taking in images)

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I spawn up a new Docker registry and front-end webUI for it using:

```
[root@centos-reg ~]# docker run --name registry -d -p 5000:5000 -v /var/docker-reg:/docker-registry-storage lukaspustina/registry-demo

[root@centos-reg ~]# docker run -d   -e ENV_DOCKER_REGISTRY_HOST=172.25.122.190 -e ENV_DOCKER_REGISTRY_PORT=5000 -p 8080:80 konradkleine/docker-registry-frontend:v2
```

and now trying to push some images using:

```
[root@centos-reg ~]# docker push 172.25.122.190:5000/my-ubuntu
The push refers to a repository [172.25.122.190:5000/my-ubuntu]
An image does not exist locally with the tag: 172.25.122.190:5000/my-ubuntu
[root@centos-reg ~]#
```

&&

```
root@ubuntu-docker-1:~# docker pull ubuntu:16.04                            
16.04: Pulling from library/ubuntu
Digest: sha256:84c334414e2bfdcae99509a6add166bbb4fa4041dc3fa6af08046a66fed3005f
Status: Image is up to date for ubuntu:16.04
root@ubuntu-docker-1:~# docker tag ubuntu:16.04 172.25.122.190:5000/my-ubuntu
root@ubuntu-docker-1:~# 
root@ubuntu-docker-1:~#  docker push 172.25.122.190:5000/my-ubuntu
The push refers to a repository [172.25.122.190:5000/my-ubuntu]
Get https://172.25.122.190:5000/v1/_ping: EOF
root@ubuntu-docker-1:~#
```

But repo still shows blank:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by:

```
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --name registry-srv registry:2

docker run -it -p 8080:8080 --name registry-web --link registry-srv -e REGISTRY_URL=http://registry-srv:5000/v2 -e REGISTRY_NAME=172.25.122.190:5000 hyper/docker-registry-web
```

and now per below it shows:

[image]